# Using Mocha in functional test and getting ActionView::Template::Error: undefined method `model_name' for NilClass:Class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mocha.js

I have a very simple controller action that loads an instance variable using a call to limit like so:

```
  def index
    @questions = Question.limit(10)
  end
```

I have a very simple functional test using shoulda, test/unit and Mocha.

```
  should 'limit questions returned' do
    Question.expects(:limit)    
    get :index
  end
```

I get the following error only when I put the mock in the test. Up to this point, everything works in the browser and in all of my other tests. If I put the mock call after the call to get:index, it fails as I would expect.

```
test: WelcomeController should limit questions returned. (WelcomeControllerTest):ActionView::Template::Error: undefined method `model_name' for NilClass:Class
app/views/welcome/index.html.erb:7:in `_app_views_welcome_index_html_erb__4244593822102250638_70180558144100'
test/functional/welcome_controller_test.rb:14:in `block in <class:WelcomeControllerTest>'
```

As I mentioned. Everything works through my integration tests and I can see this all work in a browser. I only get the error when I put in the "Question.expects(:limit)" line. I'm hoping this is just some stupid thing I'm missing. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix this by changing my view code from this:

```
    <%= render @questions %>

<% if @questions.count >= 10 %>
    <h3><%= link_to 'See more ->', questions_path %></h3>
<% end %>
```

to this:

```
<% if @questions %>
<%= render @questions %>

<% if @questions.count >= 10 %>
    <h3><%= link_to 'See more ->', questions_path %></h3>
<% end %>
<% end %>
```

I probably should have code like this in place anyway in case nothing is returned from my controller action.

So as it turns out, it was something stupid I was doing.